# How do you run a python script where the tkinter GUI is in the same file? How do you process user entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python script that does stuff with pandas. I've created a GUI in tkinter that will assign user inputs to different global variables. I need to keep everything in the same file. Here is a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
#Global Variables with default values
Winrate = 0

# Button Functions
def getWinRate():
    global Winrate
    Winrate = win_rate_entry.get()
    messagebox.showinfo('Successful Entry!')

def RunPipelineScript():
    print("Do stuff")

start_script_btn = Button(window, text="Start Script", command= RunPipelineScript())
# Rest of the script is below. It uses the values inputted by the user, e.g. WinRate entry, in the #calculations
```

I essentially want to make it so that when the Start Script button is clicked the rest of the script executes. I'm not sure how to go about this. Should I just paste the rest of the script into the "`RunPipelineScript`" function? If so will the global variables have been changed based on the users entries? Could I just make it so that once the user has inputted the appropriate entries the `RunPipelineScript` function will just jump to a certain line and continue to execute the program as normal?

As you can see I'm a novice at Python and Pandas, and any help you can provide would be most appreciated :)

Comment: You have to add the rest of the script to the function you want to call when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. You just need to do some simple steps; that is you just need to do a function in function thing.

Let's take your code for explanation.
Here:
This button, when clicked will execute the `RunPipelineScript` function.

Well if you want to execute the whole script you have to place everything inside the `RunPipeLine` function.

Also you have declare a global variable in the function too.
Thus add this just after declaring the funtion:

```
global Winrate
```

The code after alteration:

```
Winrate = 0

def RunPipelineScript():
    global Winrate
    print("Do stuff")
    # Button Functions
    def getWinRate():
        global Winrate
        Winrate = win_rate_entry.get()
        messagebox.showinfo('Successful Entry!')

        # Add all the code inside this function you want. That will execute the whole script.

start_script_btn = Button(window, text="Start Script", command= RunPipelineScript)
# Rest of the script is below. It uses the values inputted by the user, e.g. WinRate entry, in the #calculations
```

Comment: Did you notice that you repeat the error on the line `command=RunPipelineScript()`? It should be `command=RunPipelineScript` instead.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to check it. Well I am editing that issue right away. Sorry! Thanks for pointing it out.